# Realloc Not Copying Old Data

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, calloc

Background:

I created an array using calloc(), and everything was working great. Then I used realloc() to make the array larger. It seems to just create a new pointer with nothing in it and calling a runtime error when I try to access elements in the array.

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int *arr;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      if (i == 0) {
          if ((arr = (int *) calloc(1, sizeof(int))) == NULL) {
              printf("NO MORE SPACE TERMINATING PROGRAM");

              return NULL;
          }

      } else {
          int *tmp;

          if ((tmp = (int *)realloc(arr, 4*sizeof(int)) == NULL)){
              printf("NO MORE SPACE TERMINATING PROGRAM");
          }

          arr = tmp;
      }

      arr[i] = i;
  }
}
```

It throws a runtime error on the line `arr[i]=i;` when i = 1;

When I add a breakpoint 1 line above `arr = temp;` it shows that temp is completely blank.

Why is this happening?

--------Update----------------

Thanks for all of the help. Here is the working updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int *arr = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        int *tmp;

        if ((tmp = realloc(arr, (i+1) * sizeof(int))) == NULL){
            printf("NO MORE SPACE TERMINATING PROGRAM");
        }

        arr = tmp;

        arr[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%i",arr[i]);
    }
}
```

The output is: 01234

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: You don't `#include <stdlib.h>`, which is exactly why you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`. Also `arr[4]` is one element beyond the 4 you `realloc` (3 is the maximum index you can address with a 4 element array).

Comment: Not related to your problem, but the `i == 0` case is redundant if you used `int *arr = NULL;` originally. It's safe to realloc a null pointer and it behaves the same as `malloc` in that case.

Comment: Also, as a matter of style `for (i = 0; ___; i++) { if (i == 0) {....}` would be more clearly written by just having the `{....}` block before the start of the loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always heed the warnings. Doing so would show:

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
           if ((tmp = (int *)realloc(arr, 4*sizeof(int)) == NULL)){
```

Which tells you that the compiler is assigning an `int` to `tmp`. How is that possible? If you look carefully you will find that the parentheses are not correct. In effect it is assigining the result of `realloc(arr, 4*sizeof(int)) == NULL` to `tmp`. The correct code is below. Note where the parentheses are around the assignment.

```
if ((tmp = realloc(arr, 4*sizeof(int))) == NULL)
```

And you are missing `#include <stdlib.h>` for the definitions of `calloc` and `realloc`.

Update: As suggested by M.M and others, even if the above is fixed, the `realloc` is still not correct because it only allocates 4 elements whereas the `for` loop will access 5 elements. So need to change the `4` to `5` or `i+1` for example. And even though it doesn't cause any functional problems, it's unnecessary to `realloc` on every loop after 0.

Comment: It might also be good to mention that `4` is not enough; perhaps `(i+1)` would be better